# Mixing Rcpp modules and Rcpp::export

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I want to expose a C++ class and a function that takes objects of that class as a parameter to R. I have to following simplified example. I created a package using

```
Rscript -e 'Rcpp::Rcpp.package.skeleton("soq")'
```

and put the following code in `soq_types.h`

```
#include <RcppCommon.h>
#include <string>

class Echo {
  private:
  std::string message;
  public:
  Echo(std::string message) : message(message) {}
  Echo(SEXP);

  std::string get() { return message; }
};

#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

RCPP_MODULE(echo_module) {
  class_<Echo>("Echo")
  .constructor<std::string>()
  .method("get", &Echo::get)
  ;
};

//// [[Rcpp::export]]
void shout(Echo e) {
  Rcout << e.get() << "!" << std::endl;
}
```

Note that the last comment has extra slashes and doesn't cause the function to be exported. When I now run:

```
$> Rscript -e 'Rcpp::compileAttributes()'
$> R CMD INSTALL .

R> library(Rcpp)
R> suppressMessages(library(inline))
R> library(soq)
R> echo_module <- Module("echo_module", getDynLib("soq"))
R> Echo <- echo_module$Echo
R> e <- new(Echo, "Hello World")
R> print(e$get())
```

everything is fine. Unfortunately, if I enable the `Rcpp::export`, do `compileAttributes()` and re-install I get:

```
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘soq’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/home/brj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-soq/00new/soq/libs/soq.so':
  /home/brj/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/00LOCK-soq/00new/soq/libs/soq.so: undefined symbol: _ZN4EchoC1EP7SEXPREC
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
```

My question is: how do I get both to work?

I'm on R.3.6.3 and

```
R> sessionInfo()
....
other attached packages:
[1] inline_0.3.15 Rcpp_1.0.4.6 
....
```

### Addendum

For those trying to follow the example above: it's very important that the source file is exactly named `<package_name>_types.h`. Otherwise, the auto-generated `RcppExports.cpp` will not `#include` it and thus the `Echo` class will not be defined there. This will cause a compilation error.

Comment: Scratching my head a little to think of the best example and failing.  I think we do that _somewhere_ but now I can't point to where :-/   Try, for starters, to split the Rcpp Modules busines from the compileAttributes business by using two files.  Use `inst/include/packagename_types.h` is you need a joint header.

Comment: This isn't your problem here, but I'm also kind of wondering how this would even work. I have a limited understanding of how Modules work. But my understanding is you can't pass it an `Echo` object from the R side. You can pass it an S4 object from the R side (called an Echo class in R), or you can pass it a pointer to the `Echo` object you create with `e <- new(Echo, "Hello World")`, but I don't think you can pass an `Echo` object itself. Is that right @DirkEddelbuettel , or am I way off base here? Like I say, Modules isn't one of the corners of `Rcpp` I haven't visited often.

Comment: Good point. Rcpp Attributes may not know about conversion of `Echo`.  Missed that on the way out the door earlier.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this, I'm playing a bit more with it now I know I'm not missing something too obvious. This probably doesn't surprise you but adding a constructor such as `Echo::Echo(SEXP sexp) { Rcout << "USELESS!" << std::endl; }` gives runnable code that doesn't initialize field `message`.

Comment: Also, I can't get the alternative: `RCPP_MODULE(shout_module) { function("shout", &shout); }` working either, it gives the same error.

Comment: Why don't you make `shout` a method of your class and do as @duckmayr suggests using `new`? You could then do something like `e$shout()`.

Comment: @JosephWood To provide a bit more context: At my day job, `Echo` is an RNG that re-implements parts of Java's COLT random number generation. As a temporary solution I just added another method to RNG instead of passing it but I dislike this for two reasons: 1) What if I want to pass two classes to one function? 2) The method I've now added to my RNG class doesn't belong there (IMO).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is complaining about the declared but not defined `Echo(SEXP)`, which is meant to extend `Rcpp::as<>`. For classes handled by Rcpp modules it is easier to use the `RCPP_EXPOSED_*` macros:

```cpp
 #include <Rcpp.h>

class Echo {
private:
    std::string message;
public:
    Echo(std::string message) : message(message) {}

    std::string get() { return message; }
};

RCPP_EXPOSED_AS(Echo);

using namespace Rcpp;

RCPP_MODULE(echo_module) {
    class_<Echo>("Echo")
    .constructor<std::string>()
    .method("get", &Echo::get)
    ;
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
void shout(Echo e) {
    Rcout << e.get() << "!" << std::endl;
}

/***R
e <- new(Echo, "Hello World")
print(e$get())
shout(e)
*/
```

Output:

```r
> Rcpp::sourceCpp('62228538.cpp')

> e <- new(Echo, "Hello World")

> print(e$get())
[1] "Hello World"

> shout(e)
Hello World!
```

All this was not inside a package but using `Rcpp::sourceCpp`. I would expect it to work in a package as well, though.

Comment: Thanks, can confirm it works in my test package as well!

Comment: Now between the two of you can we get a quick Rcpp Gallery writeup to document this more clearly?

Comment: I'm reading through existing examples right now and will take a stab it. I hope to send something by e-mail if that's OK.