# Constructor error when working with classes in Rcpp

Tags: c++, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I'm trying to integrate classes into an R package that uses Rcpp (Armadillo), but I'm struggling with the constructor.

**Cpp_classes.cpp**

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends("RcppArmadillo")]]


class NormalDistribution {
  private:
    double mean;
    double sd;
    
  public:
    NormalDistribution(double argMean, double argSd) : mean(argMean), sd(argSd) {}
    
    double AddMeanAndSd(){
      return mean + sd;
    }
};

RCPP_EXPOSED_AS(NormalDistribution);

using namespace Rcpp;

RCPP_MODULE(NormalDistribution_module) {
  class_<NormalDistribution>("NormalDistribution")
  .constructor()
  .method("AddMeanAndSd", &NormalDistribution::AddMeanAndSd)
  ;
};


// [[Rcpp::export]]
arma::vec DoSomething(arma::vec x, NormalDistribution norm) {
  return x + norm.AddMeanAndSd();
}
```

When I try to source the file I get the following error message:

> No matching function for call to NormalDistribution::NormalDistribution().

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62228538/mixing-rcpp-modules-and-rcppexport) but can't figure out where the error comes from. Would appreciate any help and hints.

Comment: "No matching function for call to NormalDistribution::NormalDistribution()" - What's so hard to understand? The compiler error seems perfectly clear. Your `NormalDistribution` doesn't have a default constructor.

Comment: I changed it to `.constructor<double,double>()` and now it aborts my R session instead.